# What is this symbol in “The Finite Element Method” by Thomas Hughes

Tags: notation, finite-element-method

I'm reading this book *The Finite Element Method: Linear Static and Dynamic Finite Element Analysis* by Thomas J. R. Hughes. Does anyone know what these symbols (and their font) are in the picture?

[image]

They look like l and g but apparently they are not. Thanks!

Comment: I think they look like $f$ and $g$ in some script font. The third one in each row looks to be bolded (maybe).

Comment: This is almost certainly $f, f_i, \mathbf f$ and $g, g_i, \mathbf g$ in a cursive font (especially since the next line continues with what is clearly $h, h_i, \mathbf h$ in the same cursive font). I assume the three symbol are for scalar, vector component, and vector.

Comment: Thanks Lubin and Misha!!